# Trouble Plotting Mobius Strip in Maple 17

Tags: maple

I'm quite new to Maple, so forgive me if this question seems a little trivial. I'm trying to plot a Mobius strip with the parametrization $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
[1+tcos(s)]cos(2s)\\ [1+tcos(s)]sin(2s)
\\ tsin(s)
\end{matrix}\right.$$ with the parameters of $$0\leq s\leq \pi$$ $$-1/5\leq t\leq1/5$$

What I have so far is:

```
 Student[VectorCalculus]
 with(plots):

 f:=[1+t*cos(s)]*cos(2*s)
 g := [1+t*cos(s)]*sin(2*s)
 h := t*sin(s)
 plot3d([f, g, h], s = 0 .. Pi, t = -1/5 .. 1/5)
```

Alternatively, I also tried this:

```
 plot3d([[1+t*cos(s)]*cos(2*s), [1+t*cos(s)]*sin(2*s), t*sin(s)], s = 0 .. Pi, t = -1/5 .. 1/5)
```

Neither returns a plot. Is there something wrong with my code? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maple is case-sensitive.  The function is plot3d, not plot3D.  Also parentheses () and brackets [] have different meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RobertIsrael already mentioned, maple is case sensitive. Apart from that you cannot use square brackets `[]` and parenthesis `()` interchangeably. Use square brackets for lists and parenthesis for the usual parenthesization.

The following code works perfectly fine. I just adjusted the `D` to lower case and the inner square brackets to parenthesis.

```
> with(plots);
> plot3d([(1+t*cos(s))*cos(2*s), (1+t*cos(s))*sin(2*s), t*sin(s)], s = 0 .. Pi, t = -1/5 .. 1/5);
```

Comment: Lists, not vectors.

Comment: Right  that is what I wanted to say, I confused it with Matlab=) Thank you!

Comment: Ohh I see. Thank you!